# How can I get the next time it's 14:00?

Tags: javascript, date, time, datejs

Is it possible to get the next time it's 14:00 (for example) as a `Date` object in Javascript using Datejs?

The documentation doesn't seem to show such an example and trying `next 14:00` doesn't really seem to work.

Comment: well if its not documented then its probably doesn't support it,but you can easily implement this by yourself,check if then current HH is bigger then 14  -> get tomorrow at 14:00 , if equals to 14 -> check if minutes equals to 0. if HH smaller then 14 -> get today at 14:00

Comment: Disappointing absence of basic research and thought, for a 47.6k-rep long-time user.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why do you say that?

Comment: Note that the original date.js is mostly dormant.  Please read [the datejs tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info), then take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) or use RobG's fine answer that needs no library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a library for this. You can create a Date object and if it's after 14:00, set the date to tomorrow, then set time to 14:00.

#### Edit

The original would allow any time from 14:00 to 14:59:59.999 as it only checked the hours. Updated so that any time from 14:00:00.001 to 23:59:59.999 is treated as after 14:00.

Also added Date.js version (the [documentation](https://code.google.com/archive/p/datejs/wikis/APIDocumentation.wiki) for which is minimal — perhaps there's something better).

```js
// Create a date for now and remember the time
var d = new Date();
var time = +d;

// Set the time to 14:00 and, if earlier than now, add a day
d.setHours(14,0,0,0);
if ( d < time) {
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
}

document.write('Next 14:00: ' + d)
```

Here is the Date.js version. I couldn't find a CDN to include as a snippet.

```
// Equivalent using Date.js
var d = Date.present();
var t = +d;
d.set({hour:14});
if (d < t) {
  d.addDays(1);
}

document.write('<br>' + d3);
```

Or, as one line:

```
Date.today().set({hour:14}).isBefore(Date.present())? Date.today().addDays(1).set({hour:14}) : Date.today().set({hour:14});

// Or
Date.today().set({hour:14}).addDays(Date.today().set({hour:14}).isBefore(Date.present())? 1:0);
```

I don't recommend the one liner versions; they're just there to show it can be done. They each create 3 date objects, whereas the other versions create only 1.

Comment: Eh, -1 not enough Datejs

Comment: @Shoe—fair enough, how about now? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to use Datejs, but here is a simple solution in pure JavaScript. Hopefully it helps a bit. This sample gets the current date and checks if it is already past 14:00, and if so, creates a Date object for 14:00 the next day. If it is not already past 14:00, it creates a Date object for 14:00 that day.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
if (currentDate.getHours() >= 14){
    var newDate = new Date(currentDate.getYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate()+1, 14, 0, 0, 0);
}
else{
    var newDate = new Date(currentDate.getYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate(), 14, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: you'll need to add another `if` to check when the hour is 14 and minute is 0 also he already mentioned that hes using a package that deals the dates,no need to rewrite the functionality.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well the first part I mentioned might be useless,depends on whats hes trying to do but there's really no reason to re-implement  the date functions